# Using the result of a query to display images inside a php while loop one after the other

Tags: php, jquery

This is a continuation of a post which I could not get an answer that works so I here I go again.

I am trying to display images using data returned by a mySQL query. The query returns the names of an image files and a timelapse which is a number (seconds). I need to display each image for the number of seconds returned in `TimeLapse`.

With help from my first post I am able to display images that are static but not from the result of the query.

The static method works and displays all the images one after the other

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="1000"><img src="/<?=$ImagePath?>doubletreelandscapeoverridedemo.png" class="responsive"/></div>
  <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="2000"><img src="/<?=$ImagePath?>covidtest.png" class="responsive"/></div>
  <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="6000"><img src="/<?=$ImagePath?>gilhrsignagedemol.png" class="responsive"/></div>
</div>
```

Using the query result displays only the first image

```html
<?php while($row = $fb->fetch_array()): ?>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="<?=$row['TimeLapse']?>">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <a>
          <img src="/<?=$ImagePath . $row['SignageImageName']?>" class="responsive"/>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

```js
(function() {
  $("div.outer div.banner-container").hide();
  run();

  function run() {
    // get a list of all the banners
    var banners = $("div.outer div.banner-container");
    if (!banners.length) {
      return;
    }
    // active is the one with "active" class, or the first one
    var active = banners.filter(".active").first();
    if (!active.length) {
      active = banners.first();
    }
    // get the next one or loop to the beginning again
    var next = active.next("div.banner-container");
    if (!next.length) {
      next = banners.first();
    }
    active.fadeOut(500).removeClass("active");
    next.fadeIn(500).addClass("active");
    // get the delay time from the data-delay-time attribute
    setTimeout(run, next.data("delayTime"));
  }
})();
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the PHP loop which creates the `div` elements is in the wrong place. You repeat the entire `.outer` structure multiple times with each containing a single `.banner-container`.

You should instead loop inside the single `.outer` and create multiple `.banner-container` elements within it, like this:

```
<div class="outer">
  <?php while($row = $fb->fetch_array()): ?>
    <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="<?=$row['TimeLapse']?>">
      <div>
        <a>
          <img src="/<?=$ImagePath . $row['SignageImageName']?>" class="responsive"/>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile ?>
</div>
```

Note that I removed the `id` attribute from the HTML in the loop as this will result in duplicates which is invalue.

With this correction made your code works correctly:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  run();

  function run() {
    var banners = $("div.outer div.banner-container");
    if (!banners.length) {
      return;
    }
    
    // active is the one with "active" class, or the first one
    var active = banners.filter(".active").first();
    if (!active.length) {
      active = banners.first();
    }
    
    // get the next one or loop to the beginning again
    var next = active.next("div.banner-container");
    if (!next.length) {
      next = banners.first();
    }
    active.fadeOut(500).removeClass("active");
    next.fadeIn(500).addClass("active");
    
    // get the delay time from the data-delay-time attribute
    setTimeout(run, next.data("delayTime"));
  }
});
```

```css
div.outer div.banner-container { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="2000">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <a><img src="/foo.jpg" class="responsive" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="2000">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <a><img src="/foo.jpg" class="responsive" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="2000">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <a><img src="/foo.jpg" class="responsive" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I used CSS to hide the `div.outer div.banner-container` elements on load in order to avoid a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content), and also converted the IIFE in your JS logic to a document.ready event handler to ensure that the jQuery code always executes *after* the DOM has loaded.